# JPA CascadeType.ALL does not work by query?

Tags: java, jpa

I have `OneToMany` bidirectional relationship enity classes (`WorkOrder` and `Task`). `WorkOrder` have one or more `Task`.
when I delete a `WorkOrder` enity by **query**, I get foreign key constraint exception. `EntityManager` can't delete related `Task` automatically.

My question : Does Is `CascadeType.REMOVE` used by `em.removed(..)` method? Is it not used by `query`?(delete query).

WorkOrder.java

```
.....
public class WorkOrder {
    ....
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date expiryDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="workOrder", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Task> taskList;
    ......
}
```

Task.java

```
......
public class Task {
    .....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORK_ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private WorkOrder workOrder;
    .....
}
```

I need to delete `WorkOrder` based on expiry date. I need to delete related `Task` firstly, after that I have to delete `WorkOrder`. Is it correct?
I think, it will be better `CascadeType` could used by `Query`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "by Query"?  Should you be using the entityManager to delete?

Comment: @kmb385, What I mean is I delete an entity by using `NameQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I would recommend using the entity manager.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the spec, DELETE by query (query starting "DELETE FROM ...") does not trigger such callbacks (since it is a way of removing data from the datastore quickly); callbacks are only used by the normal persistence operations (persist, merge, refresh, remove) so if you want their behaviour to be followed then use *remove()*

Comment: Will `Query` effect on `CascadeType`?

Comment: Just as DataNucleus said - em.remove(-) is a remove JPA operation and it obeys the cascade behaviour. JPQL query that starts with DELETE (it's actually named "bulk delete" or native DELETE SQL query both omit the cascade behaviour. It's part of the JPA 2.0 spec.