# Child objects are not deleted even though I have cascading on

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Why are not feedback deleted when I delete food? I have the following mapping on the set of feedback. Issuing a named query like this `delete from Food where id = :id` . (Yes, I set the id on removal).

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "food_id")
private Set<Feedback> feedback;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [JPA CascadeType.ALL does not work by query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681567/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-work-by-query).

JPQL Delete queries do not trigger cascade.

Use EntityManager.remove() instead

Comment: So does that mean if I want to mimic deletion by id and get all the JPA magic I need to do a find operation first, and then use the normal remove method on the entitymanager?